Was Hiram Rhoades Revels allowed to use the Senate washrooms?
Hiram Revels, the first Black member of Congress in the U.S., was elected in 1870.  He faced some transient opposition to taking his seat... in the Senate.  But considering the infamous U.S. history of segregated toilets, was he blocked from using some or all of the restroom facilities normally used by Senators?
(FWIW - Perplexity.ai spoke of a "lack of explicit records" and "no documented evidence" in responding to this question.  I'm not even sure if I'm thinking anachronistically, if this type of segregation only started during the Jim Crow era.  The historical context of my curiosity is obvious, but not relevant to this particular question.)

Yes, you're thinking anachronistically. Formal legal segregation of public accomodations came after Reconstruction, and started in the deep south, not DC.

One book claims that "Although no official segregation laws existed, in practice the visitors’ galleries in both the House and Senate were segregated by gender and race."

@user182601 - That's a way of saying that people were self-segregating by choice, like happens a lot in say modern public school lunchrooms. Perhaps that's not an ideal look for the future, but its pretty different from having systemic state-enforced segregation.

@T.E.D.: people were self-segregating by choice White persons may have been "self-segregating by choice", but black persons certainly weren't doing so.
